# CocoaPods: "Generating support files" takes too long, anyway to improve?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoapods

I use CocoaPods in my project but every time I change something it takes a long time to generate support files, I know it is not something I can control, but just wonder is it something that it generates for sub-libraries, if so, can I save the existing 'support files' and only let it generate the one for newly added libs?

I run 'pod install' every time when I change the Podfile, is it a problem and I should run 'pod setup' instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are working on it:

```
# AWSiOSSDK is a good test because it has a lot of files
$ find Pods/AWSiOSSDK | wc -l
3001

# and generates a plist with almost 80k lines
$ wc -l Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
79766 Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

# CocoaPods 0.15.1
$ time pod install --no-integrate --silent
pod install --no-integrate --silent  216,50s user 1,45s system 83% cpu 4:19,68 total

# Modified CocoaPods
$ time dpod install --no-integrate --silent
COCOA_PODS_ENV=development ~/Documents/GitHub/CP/CocoaPods/bin/pod install    8,03s user 0,67s system 55% cpu 15,802 total
```

More than 4 minutes vs 16s means that the generate support phase should become pretty fast in CocoaPods 0.16.

From [Xcodeproj/pull/34](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/pull/34)

So I can only suggest to wait :-)

Comment: Thanks, do you have a estimate how long can it take to be released?